# Recursive struct and malloc()

Tags: c, struct, malloc, recursive-datastructures

I have a recursive `struct` which is:

```
typedef struct dict dict;
struct dict {
    dict *children[M];
    list *words[M];
};
```

Initialized this way:

```
dict *d = malloc(sizeof(dict));
bzero(d, sizeof(dict));
```

I would like to know what `bzero()` exactly does here, and how can I `malloc()` recursively for children.

**Edit**: This is how I would like to be able to `malloc()` the `children` and `words`:

```
void dict_insert(dict *d, char *signature, unsigned int current_letter, char *w) {
    int occur;
    occur = (int) signature[current_letter];
    if (current_letter == LAST_LETTER) {
        printf("word found : %s!\n",w);
        list_print(d->words[occur]);
        char *new;
        new = malloc(strlen(w) + 1);
        strcpy(new, w);
        list_append(d->words[occur],new);
        list_print(d->words[occur]);
    }
    else {
        d = d->children[occur];
        dict_insert(d,signature,current_letter+1,w);
    }
}
```

Comment: When would the recursion stop?

Comment: According to man pages, `bzero` is deprecated.  Use `calloc` or `malloc`/`memset` instead.

Comment: What I do not understand is what is the point of having `bzero()` here?

Comment: @DietrichEpp I have a `#define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void) 0)` definition to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you are unsure what the compiler is generating for you, it is a good idea to use a printf to report the size of the struct. In this case, the size of dict should be 2 * M * the size of a pointer. In this case, bzero will fill a dict with zeros. In other words, all M elements of the children and words arrays will be zero.

To initialize the structure, I recommend creating a function that takes a pointer to a dict and mallocs each child and then calls itself to initialize it:

```
void init_dict(dict* d)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        d->children[i] = malloc(sizeof(dict));
        init_dict(d->children[i]);

        /* initialize the words elements, too */
    }
}
```

+1 to you if you can see why this code won't work as is. (Hint: it has an infinite recursion bug and needs a rule that tells it how deep the children tree needs to be so it can stop recursing.)

Comment: A `depth` rule is needed like the one in the answer above yours :)

Comment: Correct! I leave it to you to know what form it should take. I decided not to use one like Jerry's because it was not obvious to me that you needed a tree of uniform depth. Perhaps the depth of a branch should depend on the data stored within it. I couldn't tell.

Comment: Yes, the depth is uniform : each branch can have a depth of 26 (depth = 1 for letter a and depth = 26 for letter z). I have explained what I am trying to achieve in Jerry's answer, that may help you understand my problem :)

Comment: 26?!? So if the top-level node has M children, and each child has M children, and there are 26 generations of children, then there are M +  M^2 + M^3 + ... + M^26 nodes. That's a lot of nodes. Good thing RAM is cheap. :)

Comment: Yes that is why I can't allocate memory for the entire tree but only for the nodes needed.

Answer (score 2):

[`bzero(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero) initializes the memory to zero.  It's equivalent to calling [`memset(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) with a second parameter of 0.  In this case, it initializes all of the member variables to null pointers.  `bzero` is considered deprecated, so you should replace uses of it with `memset`; alternatively, you can just call [`calloc(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) instead of `malloc`, which automatically zeroes out the returned memory for you upon success.

You should not use either of the two casts you have written—in C, a `void*` pointer can be implicitly cast to any other pointer type, and any pointer type can be implicitly cast to `void*`.  `malloc` returns a `void*`, so you can just assign it to your `dict *d` variable without a cast.  Similarly, the first parameter of `bzero` is a `void*`, so you can just pass it your `d` variable directly without a cast.

To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.  Make sure you have an appropriate base case if you want to avoid allocating memory infinitely.

Comment: What is the point of initializing the memory to zero? I have deleted the casts. I would like to be able to allocate memory for only the children I want. I understand the recursion, but I am bad at allocating memory. I could use some help here :)

Answer (score 1):

`bzero` just zeros the memory. `bzero(addr, size)` is essentially equivalent to `memset(addr, 0, size)`. As to why you'd use it, from what I've seen around half the time it's used, it's just because somebody though zeroing the memory seemed like a good idea, even though it didn't really accomplish anything. In this case, it looks like the effect would be to set some pointers to NULL (though it's not entirely portable for that purpose).

To allocate recursively, you'd basically just keep track of a current depth, and allocate child nodes until you reached the desired depth. Code something on this order would do the job:

```
void alloc_tree(dict **root, size_t depth) { 
    int i;
    if (depth == 0) {
        (*root) = NULL;
        return;
    }

    (*root) = malloc(sizeof(**root));

    for (i=0; i<M; i++)
        alloc_tree((*root)->children+i, depth-1);       
}
```

I should add that I can't quite imagine doing recursive allocation like this though. In a typical case, you insert data, and allocate new nodes as needed to hold the data. The exact details of that will vary depending on whether (and if so how) you're keeping the tree balanced. For a multi-way tree like this, it's fairly common to use some B-tree variant, in which case the code I've given above won't normally apply at all -- with a B-tree, you fill a node, and when it's reached its limit, you split it in half and promote the middle item to the parent node. You allocate a new node when this reaches the top of the tree, and the root node is already full.

Comment: Yes, I would like to allocate new nodes as needed. I have edited my post to add the function used to insert data. I would like to know how to test if memory has been already allocated for this node, and how to allocate it if not.

Comment: @kh4r4: I think before I (or probably anybody) can help you a lot more, we need to understand more about the overall structure of what you're trying to do. Looking through the code you've added, I'm not at all sure I understand what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish the following: We have a list of words and we want to insert them in the tree regarding the number of times their letters appear (a letter can appear M times in a word). First we check current letter. If we reach the last letter then we insert the word in the corresponding list. If not, we call the insertion algorithm recursively on the corresponding child of current node.